# Auto calculate (Difference) input values from form with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have input fields (in my laravel project) such as ones below and want to auto calculate the Net Pay. I want a situation where when the inputs are done, the earnings add up while input in the deductions are subtracted from the the earnings given the Net Pay.

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="col">
         <label for="" style="color: red">Earnings</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <label for="" style="color: red">Deductions</label>
      </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="net_pay">Basic Salary</label>
                                    <input class="form-control earnings" id="earnings1" 
    type="number" name="basic_salary" value="{{ old('basic_salary') }}" 
    onkeyup="AutoCalc(this)">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="net_pay">SSF</label>
                                    <input class="form-control deductions" id="deductions1" type="number" name="ssf" value="{{ old('ssf') }}" onkeyup="AutoCalc(this)">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="net_pay">Allowance</label>
                                    <input class="form-control earnings" id="earnings2" 
    type="number" name="allowance" value="{{ old('allowance') }}" 
    onkeyup="AutoCalc(this)">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="net_pay">Income Tax</label>
                                    <input class="form-control deductions" 
    id="deductions2" type="number" name="income_tax" value="{{ old('income_tax') }}" 
    onkeyup="AutoCalc(this)">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    <div class="col">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="net_pay">Net Pay</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="number" 
    id="net_pay" name="net_pay" value="{{ old('net_pay') }}" readonly>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

I am having difficulty in auto generating the net_pay value using the following script:

```js
 $(function() {
        $('.deductions').keyup(function() {
            var earning = 0;
            var deduction = 0;
            $('.earnings').each(function() {
                earning += Number($(this).val());
            });
            $('.deductions').each(function() {
                deduction += Number($(this).val());
            });
            $('#net_pay').val(deduction);
        });
    });
```

I have surf for long but seem not to have solution to my challenge.
I am counting on you to help me in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, can you be more specific than "having difficulty" - is the code giving you an error, or a wrong result, or what?

Comment: There is no error. If I work with only one (either deductions or earnings) the net_pay auto calculate successfully.

Comment: Well, you dont' need the inline 'onkeyup' events because you have them all covered in your script. Also,  you may have meant to do this: `$('#net_pay').val(earning-deduction);`

Comment: without the 'onkeyup' the script is not working but seems to work with this: $('.deductions').keyup(function() {
        var earning = 0;
        var deduction = 0;
        $('.earnings').each(function() {
            earning += Number($(this).val());
        });
        $('.deductions').each(function() {
            deduction += Number($(this).val());
        });
        $('#net_pay').val(earning-deduction);
    }); However, when 'earnings' are used in the 'onkeyup', the script do not work. I want to know if the above code is okay to be adopted.

Answer (score 0):

This script worked for me:

```js
$('.deductions,.deductions').keyup(function() { var earning = 0; var deduction = 0; $('.earnings').each(function() { earning += Number($(this).val()); }); $('.deductions').each(function() { deduction += Number($(this).val()); }); $('#net_pay').val(earning-deduction); });
```